# Reconciling vmware memory vs windows memory usage

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-esxi, memory

I have a Windows 2008 R2 64 bit virtual machine on ESXi 4.1 host.  The host reports that the virtual machine is actively using less than 1 GB of memory.  But, in Windows it's reporting the machine is using 7 GB of memory, even though the total of the processes listed in task manager is less than 1 GB.  The machine is rather unresponsive and I'm concerned this is impacting other applications (server's purpose is to run ASP.NET state server process, which has been having trouble and led me to spot the memory question).

I just noticed [High memory usage Windows Server 2008r2 on VMware](https://serverfault.com/questions/240076/high-memory-usage-windows-server-2008r2-on-vmware) and will be looking through those documents more, but what is causing this?

[image: vSphere report]

[image: windows report]

Comment: Don't give a virtual machine more memory than you want it to use. the OS assumes that it's "free" to use memory and will use pretty much all you assign it whether it needs it or not.

Comment: But, what is using it? Within Windows, it is unclear what process is consuming it.  Using task manager and process explorer offered no clues.

Comment: Check with perfmon.

Comment: You have much of the data in front of you.  What does this server do?

Comment: It's only responsible for ASP.NET state server, which is using about 120 MB.  All other processes are less than 100 MB, and most are quite small.  Total (as listed in task manager and process explorer) is nowhere near 7 GB.

Comment: @RyanW: The OS doesn't care what's using it. It doesn't need it, so why would it bother doing anything about it? It believes that using that memory is totally free, and it has no better use for it, so it doesn't bother with it. As far as the OS is concerned, any effort spent on it would be wasted. (If you have a chest stored in your garage, do you go looking for it when you don't need it?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run [RAMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx) in the vm to find out how Windows is using the memory.

If Windows isn't under memory pressure, it doesn't bother to make any memory free, so memory can accumulate that is technically used but not really used. The OS assumes that there is zero cost associated with memory that is used if there's still enough available memory to meet foreseeable demand.

Comment: RAMMap reports that about 5.5 GB is "driver locked" which seems to be VMWare probably from what I've read about their memory management.

Comment: Ahh, so probably VMWare is stealing it from Windows to give back to Windows when it thinks it needs it. That's probably how they get around the "Windows thinks it's free to use RAM" issue.

Comment: ["Adjust VM memory and memory limits to be equal or dont use limits (check the ‘unlimited’ checkbox)"](http://ronnyholtmaat.nl/server-2008-64-bit-enterprise-memory-usage-driver-locked-memory/)